# Why is jquery POST not working on data: data and working on data: {data: data}?

Tags: jquery

Why is below code not working?
`json = { "color": [ {"colorId": "A"}, {"colorId": "B"}]}`

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    url: '/some/url',
    data: data;        //here data = JSON.stringify(json)
})
```

It works if:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: '/some/url',
    data: {data: data};        //here data = JSON.stringify(json)
})
```

What is `data: {data: data}` really doing to make the POST method work?

Comment: In what way does the code fail?  What's the actual observed error or incorrect result?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, what are the differences in the network requests (specifically the request payloads) for these two versions?

Comment: Most likely because the receiving logic on the server requires the information to be sent in a property named `data`, which is not included in the first example. Without seeing the server logic, this is a guess, though.

Comment: with ```data: {data: data}``` I see Form Data with the json data in the format: ```data: { json}``` . With ```data: data``` I see Form Data ```{ json}``` in the chrome

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that was a right guess. Thanks